# What's the best way to test out an app idea

Tags: user-centered-design, lean-ux

I've got a client who wants to design and develop an app where you can build personal profiles as an artist in the entertainment industry. As they are from this industry they have a lot of background knowledge and experience about it and are sure it will be successful.

My question is how should i go about testing their assumptions and fine tuning the user flow before designing or developing the app. right now i'm thinking to do a low fi click thru on Invision and test it on some of their target users. Are there any other ways i could test it out?

Comment: Interactive Prototyping? XD, Framer, Origami Studio, you the latter one can even mock HTTP requests and validate texts on the prototype itself.

Comment: What are their assumptions? Depending on if it related to the types of user, the user flow, the language or the interactions, you can come up with any different number of ways to assess the validity of the design. As the question stands at the moment it is a bit broad.

Answer (score 2):

Lo-fi clickthroughs are a good idea. [Paper prototyping is good too](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/paper-prototyping-the-practical-beginners-guide/), especially for testing early ideas.

> Paper prototyping is perfect for early stage conceptualizing. Its
> speed, ease, and simplicity, not to mention automatic documentation,
> make it far better suited for experimenting with new ideas than more
> complex digital prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting on lo-fi prototypes, I would suggest to engage with the Design Thinking or Design Sprint process. Both are used internationally by IDEO, Google and many more giants and smaller companies. The approach will guarantee that you explore the users first, discover the environment, ideate on things, spot some potential pain points and frictions, solve them and have more clarity which direction you are going to.

Design Thinking: https://designthinking.ideo.com/

Design Sprint book: https://www.thesprintbook.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems from the question you posted that your client only has ideas in their mind, they have not written down anything concrete.

If this is the case, I think using InVision would be too much work to test out assumptions on your case. You may want to start off by talking to other intended users to verify the problems identified by your client and then sketch out on paper prototyping to test certain segments of the ideas presented by your client.

The workflow design would probably come in after confirming the pain points and various segments of the paper prototype which will work.

In addition to Framer suggested above, personally I’d use POP app by Marvel. It’s easier to put the prototype together with sketches on paper.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to design in framer. It is the best for mobile apps and has good plugins, so you can create low fidelity designs faster.
Then share the link with multiple users and let them play around with it.
They would be able to click and navigate.

You can do the same with XD. It will give you a shareable link which your user can go to and test the navigation and flows.